# Multiple WIFI on Raspberry pi Zero

Tags: wifi, usb, pi-zero-w

I'm attempting to setup a Raspberry Pi zero W with an additional USB Wifi Dongle (wlan0 and wlan1) to connect to two different WIFI networks (one 2.4GHZ and the other 5GHZ).

OS information:

```
"Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
Linux hades 5.10.23+ #1406 Mon Mar 15 15:37:16 GMT 2021 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Raspberry Pi OS seems to have moved away from what I expected in /etc/network/interfaces and getting them both to connect to two different networks is challenging.   I used online guides I found using internet searches but sadly they appear to be for legacy versions of Raspbian rather than the current Raspberry Pi OS and don't work.

e.g.
https://mikestreety.medium.com/use-a-raspberry-pi-with-multiple-wifi-networks-2eda2d39fdd6

I've no issue in setting up the RPI with a single Wifi device on either network via wpa_supplicant.conf.   But when I put in two networks into wpa_supplicant.conf I get both devices join the same SSID on different IP addresses.

Default /etc/network/interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

Attempted interfaces:-

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet mannual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
iface safe inet dhcp
iface full inet dhcp
```

I've solved the issue (detailed as an answer) by installing and configuring netplan but I was wondering if anyone knew how to configure multiple wifi network without using netplan?

Comment: Does https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89058/42636 answer your question (esp point 3)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I solve extra and missing wifi interfaces?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89057/how-do-i-solve-extra-and-missing-wifi-interfaces)

Comment: Thanks tried that one.. syntax errors on using interfaces in that way.. Seems that the RPIOS interfaces usage has changed since then..

Comment: The stack exchange link is a new one..   I'll look into that thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Install netplan

```
apt install netplan.io
```

Create a netplan config file e.g./etc/netplan/00-wifis.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [192.168.8.101/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.8.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.8.1]
      access-points:
        safe:
          password: "REDACTED"
    wlan1:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        fast:
          password: "REDACTED"
```

Then I enabled it using:-

```
netplan generate
reboot
```

Which works fine.